# Tomcat can't power off when i put the shutdown port on -1

Tags: linux, tomcat7

I followed the CIS Benchmarks guide for hardening tomcat, one step, indicates that you change the sutdown port to -1 (step 1.5.2).

Ok, now, when i try to power off or restart the tomcat, it can't and shows me:

SEVERE: No port is set off. Turning off the server through SO signal. Server does not shutdown.

Anyone knows how to fix the problem without change the shutdown port?

Thanks and sorry, my english is bad.

Comment: I agree. What did you expect exactly? Off topic *and* not a real question.

Comment: I expect any form to shutdown the server when i use /etc/init.d/tomcat stop, now i have to use #kill <pid tomcat> and i would like use /etc/init.d/tomcat stop without remove the shutdown port -1.

Comment: When you don't have a real shutdown port you can't shut it down. Surely that is obvious? It would be better to leave the shutdown port alone and define address="127.0.0.1" so that it can only be shutdown from within the same host.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for me is a best solution. Really i don't know about tomcat, i learn about this while make hardening. the "address" option in this case is new for me. If you like, could create a answer with this solution